# Let $x^\star =\arg \min_{x \in C} f(x)$. Is it true that $\langle x-x^\star, \nabla f(x^\star) \rangle \ge 0$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Let $f$ be a convex function and $C$ some convex set and let 
\begin{align}
x^\star= \arg \min_{x \in C} f(x)
\end{align}  Is it true that  $\langle x-x^\star, \nabla f(x^\star) \rangle \ge 0$ for all $x\in C$.

I was trying to show this by using the fact that if $f$ is convex, then
\begin{align}
f(u)\ge f(w) + \langle u-w, \nabla f(w) \rangle 
\end{align}

For example, since we have that $f(x^\star)-f(x) \le 0$, then we have
\begin{align}
0 \ge \langle x^\star-x, \nabla f(x) \rangle  \Longrightarrow   \langle x-x^\star, \nabla f(x) \rangle .
\end{align}

However, this is not the right inequality.

Comment: Can we assume the convex function is smooth?

Comment: @paulinho only differentiable

Comment: @Lisa  It might be a good idea to edit the question by adding something like "$f$ is differentiable on $C$ (not necessarily continuously differentiable)". By the way, the result holds if $f$ is differentiable at $x^\ast$ (we do not if $f$ is differentiable on $C$).

Comment: @Renard Thanks for response. For the problem here, we only need that $f$ is differentiable at $x^\ast$, right? If so, your answer needs to be revised, right?

Comment: @Renard Thank you for telling me the information about non-smooth analysis. However, I care about that the answers for this question should only assume that $f$ is differentiable only at $x^\ast$ unless the author edit the question (as my previous comment said). In the OP, only $\nabla f(x^\ast)$ is used rather than $\nabla f(x)$. Actually, the result holds if $f$ is differentiable at $x^\ast$ only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're playing with is called a Variational Inequality.

The way it works is, assume $x^*$ is a global minimizer of $f(x)$ on $C$, a convex set. Now take the derivative of 
$$
\phi(\varepsilon) = f( (1-\varepsilon)x^* + \varepsilon x')
$$
wrt to $\varepsilon$, yielding
$$
\phi'(\varepsilon) = \nabla f( (1-\varepsilon)x^* + \varepsilon x')'(x'-x^*).
$$
A necessary condition for $x^*$ to be a global minimizer is that $\phi'(0) \ge 0$, or
$$
\phi'(0) = \nabla f( x^*)'(x'-x^*) \ge 0, \quad \forall x' \in C,
$$
so that taking a directional derivative in any feasible direction $x'$ raises the value of the objective function, since $x^*$ is assumed to be the global minimizer. See how this subsumes the standard FONC's, which only apply on the interior of a set? In fact, if $x^*$ is on the interior of $C$, $\nabla f(x^*)=0$, and otherwise, $\nabla f(x^*)$ is non-zero, but characterizes the supporting hyperplane to $C$; the inequality accounts for the missing Lagrange or Kuhn-Tucker terms, $\lambda \nabla h(x^*)$ where $h$ is the constraint.

Convexity hasn't been used yet. What convexity of $f$ is buying is that the solution set of the variational inequality is a convex set. So if $x^*$ and $x'$ are global minimizers and $f$ is convex,
$$
f(\lambda x^* + (1-\lambda)x') \le \lambda f(x^*) + (1-\lambda) f(x') = f^*
$$
and the convex combination $\lambda x^* + (1-\lambda)x'$ must also be a global minimizer. If $f$ is strictly convex, that inequality would yield a contradiction, so that the minimizer is unique.

In general the VI framework generalizes standard FONC/SOSC reasoning to account for solutions on the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there exists $x\in C$ such that $\langle x - x^\ast, \nabla f(x^\ast)\rangle < 0$.

Since $x^\ast + \alpha (x-x^\ast)\in C$ for each $\alpha \in [0, 1)$.
Let $g(\alpha) \triangleq f(x^\ast + \alpha (x-x^\ast)) - f(x^\ast)$ for $\alpha \in [0, 1)$.

Since $f$ is differentiable at $x^\ast$, we know that $g$ is differentiable at $0$ and
$g'(0) = \langle x - x^\ast, \nabla f(x^\ast)\rangle$.

Since $g(0) = 0$ and $g'(0) < 0$, there exists some $\alpha_0$ in $(0, 1)$ such that $g(\alpha_0) < 0$, i.e., 
$f(x^\ast + \alpha_0 (x-x^\ast)) < f(x^\ast)$ which contradicts the optimality of $x^\ast$.

We are done.